# Is there a way to get whole section group in .Net 6.0 Configuration using IConfiguration interface

Tags: .net, configurationmanager

Is there a way to access the whole section Group in .Net 6.0 Configuration from custom json file?

There's a custom json injected into configuration on startup using AddJsonFile() method.

When attempting to get the values of the file, it is possible to access only one single value with GetSection("Foo:Bar") using IConfiguration.

Is there a way to get the list of objects by using only group key or whole Json file's content as a string?

Json file's content:

```
{
  "Versions": {
    "fullVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "clientVersion": "2022.01.10",
    "apiVersion": "2022.05.09"
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public VersionController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public Version GetAllVersionsFromJson()
    {
       // Not getting the content here
       var versionsList = _configuration.GetSection("Versions");
       // Getting only one object out of 3
       var singleVersion = _configuration.GetSection("Versions:fullVersion");

       /*More logic*/

    }
```

Version class:

```
public class Version
{        
    public string Label { get; set; }
    
    public string BuildNumber { get; set; }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the data and fill in Version class, but I consider this not to be an ideal solution.

I've changed name of the section in json and added new helper model to be an exact match for the json's data:

```
public class VersionConfigurations
{
    public string fullVersion { get; set; }
    public string clientVersion { get; set; }
    public string apiVersion { get; set; }
}
```

After that the data was neatly matched in the controller:

```
   var configVerions = _configuration.GetSection("VersionConfigurations").Get<VersionConfigurations>();
```

Then the part I am not too happy about: reading names of properties and their values and getting  the versions into version list:

```
    foreach (var configVer in configVerions.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        versionsList.Add(new Version()
        {
            Label = configVer.Name,
            BuildNumber = (string)configVer.GetValue(configVerions)
        });
    };
```